# How to update the view when using maps with Angular CDK DnD?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have a small list with some items that can be reordered ([see stackblitz](https://angular-yypzib--4200.local.webcontainer.io)). Internally that list is implemented as a map. Conveniently, Angular provides the pipe keyvalue, which allows an easy way to iterate over maps like this:

```
*ngFor="let item of doc.items | keyvalue:sortHash"
```

You can provide a function, sortHash that will take care of sorting the list.
I want to use `cdkDropList` in order to provide DnD ordering to the list. This is trivial when using arrays:

```
(cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event, doc.items, doc)
```

You have to simply pass a function to `cdkDropListDropped` that will take care of moving the item within the array. Angular provides a built-in function `moveItemInArray` that does so:

```
import { moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
...
async dropItem(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>, list: any, doc: any) {
  moveItemInArray(list, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

This works as expected with arrays, but in my case, I rely on maps where the order is defined by a property "order", see my data structure:

```
  doc = {
    meta: {
      text: 'title',
      ...
    },
    items: {
      SEC_000000: {
        meta: {
          text: 'Episode I - The Phantom Menace',
          order: '0',
          ...
        },
      },
      SEC_111111: {
        meta: {
          text: 'Episode II - Attack of the Clones',
          order: '1',
          ...
        },
      },
      SEC_222222: {
        meta: {
          text: 'Episode III - Revenge of the Sith',
          order: '2',
          ...
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

hence my `dropItem` function is a bit different, it

1. transforms my map (`doc.items`) into an array
2. then uses the built-in `moveItemInArray` function to effectively move the item inside the array
3. then updates the  "order" property of all items, and finally
4. transforms the array back into a map

The sorting function works as expected, but the UI does not update when DnD.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://angular-yypzib--4200.local.webcontainer.io) with a simplified sample code. What am I missing here?

Comment: `sortHash()` is only being run when the view is initialized. It's not being re-run on drop.

Comment: @Meqwz not sure why the pipe keyvalue + sortHash don't refresh the view when the data is changed... is there a way to force an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies deep in the Angular core.
You are using the `KeyValuePipe`. [Source here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/pipes/keyvalue_pipe.ts).

The part of the pipe we are interested in is this:

```js
    const differChanges: KeyValueChanges<K, V>|null = this.differ.diff(input as any);
    const compareFnChanged = compareFn !== this.compareFn;

    if (differChanges || compareFnChanged) {
      this.keyValues.sort(compareFn);
      this.compareFn = compareFn;
    }
```

If the differ finds a difference in the input object, the sort function is run.

You can console log `differChanges` and see that it consistently returns `null` after the view is initialized. Why? We need to look at  [the differ code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.ts):

```js
  // Add the record or a given key to the list of changes only when the value has actually changed
  private _maybeAddToChanges(record: KeyValueChangeRecord_<K, V>, newValue: any): void {
    if (!Object.is(newValue, record.currentValue)) {
      record.previousValue = record.currentValue;
      record.currentValue = newValue;
      this._addToChanges(record);
    }
  }
```

The differ is using `Object.is(newValue, record.currentValue)` to determine if the value has changed. The value of the object to be diffed in this case is an object itself, and `Object.is()` does not evaluate deep equality.

So you have at least two options:

- Write your own keyvalue pipe that works the way you want it to.
- Use a different data structure to hold your movie info

[I've created a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yypzib-dwrpyj?file=src/app/key-value-custom.pipe.ts) with a custom brute-force resorting strategy `keyvalue` pipe.

Comment: Very well explained, thanks for this. I wonder if there is an easy way to extend the KeyValuePipe pipe instead of writing my own.

Comment: You can extend Angular pipes, figuring it out for this particular problem was beyond my time budget.